# Recuperar valor MAX de uma coluna SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

```
    string var = "";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Banco._strCon);
    string sql = "select max(end_id) from endereco";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
        var = (dr["max"]).ToString();

    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
    return var;
```

Preciso desse valor do `max`, porém, não sei o que passar dentro dos `[""]`. Se deixo assim, aparece o seguinte erro:

> dr["max"] 'dr["max"]' threw an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' object {System.IndexOutOfRangeException}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use o [`ExecuteScalar()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteScalar). Algo assim:

```
string sql = "select max(end_id) from endereco";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
con.Open();
return ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/GetMaxNumber.cs).

O `ExecuteReader()` deve ser usado para consultados aos dados como um todo, quando a consulta gerará apenas um dado único, o correto é o `ExecuteScalar()`.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Pro seu caso não precisa buscar por índice `String`:

```
    if (dr.Read())
        var = (((IDataRecord)dr)[0]).ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Caso não saiba o que colocar dentro dos `[""]` basta no `select` cujo campo usa função do `SQL` colocar o nome do campo, exemplo:

```
...
string sql = "select max(end_id) max from endereco";
...
if (dr.Read())
   var = (dr["max"]).ToString();
...
```

Mas a melhor opção mesmo de implementar nesse caso é a do Maniero.