# C# ASP.NET - Obter último valor de um Parâmetro da Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma `Stored Procedure` que insere diferentes campos. Mas no entanto há que ao ser inserido eu quero apanhar e colocar no ecrã.
Ele é inserido na base de dados na seguinte maneira:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numero", 0);
```

Ele aqui não está a inserir 0, o que está a acontecer dentro da Stored Procedure é o seguinte:

```
IF @numero=0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    SELECT TOP 1 @ult_nr=nRequesicao FROM cabecalho 
    WHERE eliminado=0
    ORDER BY 1 DESC 

    SET @ult_nr=@ult_nr+1

    INSERT INTO cabecalho(nRequesicao,nomeEmpresa,colaborador,nota,local_entrega)
    VALUES(@ult_nr,@empresa,@empregado,@obs_cab,@local)

    INSERT INTO linhas(nRequesicao,quantidade,descricao,valor,observacoes)
    VALUES(@ult_nr,@qtd,@produto,@valor,@obs_linha)

    SELECT * FROM V_Requisicao
    WHERE nrequesicao=@ult_nr
    ORDER BY id

    COMMIT
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO linhas(nRequesicao,quantidade,descricao,valor,observacoes)
    VALUES(@numero,@qtd,@produto,@valor,@obs_linha)

    SELECT * FROM V_Requisicao
    WHERE nrequesicao=@numero
    ORDER BY id

END
```

De que maneira posso obter o último valor e coloca-lo numa Label?

Comment: Embora pareça diferente eu acho que a resposta é a mesma: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94895/101

Comment: Você quer que uma StoredProcedure faça display do valor de um parâmetro de entrada? É isso mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o que você quer é obter um parâmetro de retorno da sua Stored Procedure, você pode fazer isso declarando um parâmetro do tipo "output" e recuperando esse valor depois da execução no C#. Veja no exemplo.

A declaração da SP

```
create procedure dbo.MinhaSP
    @numero int,
    @retorno int ouptput
as
    // Seu código aqui
    set @retorno = 100
```

Depois disso no C# você pode recuperar o valor da seguinte forma:

```
// seu código...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numero", 0);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@retorno", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
cmd.Parameters["@retorno"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
var ret = cmd.Parameters["@retorno"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Kawaii, se você deseja o valor de `@ult_nr`, você terá de marcalo como um parametro de saida. inclusive acho que ele não é necessario, você poderia usar o proprio `@numero`. Então modifique a sua procedure para o seguinte:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

IF @numero=0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @numero=nRequesicao + 1 FROM cabecalho 
    WHERE eliminado=0
    ORDER BY 1 DESC 

    INSERT INTO cabecalho(nRequesicao,nomeEmpresa,colaborador,nota,local_entrega)
    VALUES(@numero,@empresa,@empregado,@obs_cab,@local)   
END

INSERT INTO linhas(nRequesicao,quantidade,descricao,valor,observacoes)
VALUES(@numero,@qtd,@produto,@valor,@obs_linha)

COMMIT

SELECT * FROM V_Requisicao
WHERE nrequesicao=@numero
ORDER BY id
```

então você iria precisaria mudar a direção do seu parametro:

```
var numero = 0;
var param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@numero", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
param.Value = numero;
```

então após executar o seu comando, bastaria ler o valor do parametro.

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
numero = numero.Value as int;
```